# How to use promise hierarchy while avoiding anti pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I was trying to learn how to avoid the anti pattern as described here [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

I started with some code on JSFiddle but it does not output what I expected..

```
function sum1(x){
    return new Promise(resolve => x+1)
}

function sum2(x){
  return sum1(x)
  .then(x => x+1);
}

function sum3(x){
  return sum2(x)
  .then(x => x+1)
}

sum3(1)
.then(console.log);
```

I would expect it to print `4` but it prints nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it wrong in sum1. `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {//code here})` takes function as argument

```js
function sum1(x){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
     resolve(x + 1);
    })
}

function sum2(x){
  return sum1(x)
  .then(x => x+1);
}

function sum3(x){
  return sum2(x)
  .then(x => x+1)
}

sum3(1)
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a resolved promise by using [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```js
function sum1(x){
    return Promise.resolve(x+1)
}

function sum2(x){
  return sum1(x)
  .then(x => x+1);
}

function sum3(x){
  return sum2(x)
  .then(x => x+1)
}

sum3(1)
.then(console.log);
```